# Delphi - Permissions not granted Fmx

Tags: android, delphi, permissions, storage, firemonkey

I have an issue with my project, so I decided to test on sample gave by embarcadero :
https://github.com/Embarcadero/RADStudio11Demos/tree/main/Object%20Pascal/Mobile%20Snippets/CameraRoll

When I target Android 12 (Api 32) all is ok, but when I target Android 13 (API 33) Permissions are not granted.

I have add these permissions
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

And in the code.
But when the popup display, I accept all, and that not working.
As the permissions are not granted.

EDIT :

```
unit uMain;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants, System.Permissions,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.StdCtrls, System.Sensors, FMX.Media,
  FMX.Objects, FMX.MediaLibrary.Actions, System.Actions, FMX.ActnList, FMX.Graphics,
  FMX.StdActns, FMX.Controls.Presentation;

type
  TCameraRollForm = class(TForm)
    btnPhotoLibrary: TButton;
    imgPhotoLibraryImage: TImage;
    alGetCameraRoll: TActionList;
    TakePhotoFromLibraryAction1: TTakePhotoFromLibraryAction;
    ToolBar1: TToolBar;
    Label1: TLabel;

    procedure TakePhotoFromLibraryAction1DidFinishTaking(Image: TBitmap);
    procedure btnPhotoLibraryClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FRawBitmap: TBitmap;
    FPermissionReadExternalStorage: string;
    FPermissionWriteExternalStorage: string;

    procedure DisplayRationale(Sender: TObject; const APermissions: TClassicStringDynArray; const APostRationaleProc: TProc);
    procedure LoadPicturePermissionRequestResult(Sender: TObject; const APermissions: TClassicStringDynArray; const AGrantResults: TClassicPermissionStatusDynArray);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

var
  CameraRollForm: TCameraRollForm;

implementation

uses
{$IFDEF ANDROID}
  Androidapi.Helpers,
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes,
  Androidapi.JNI.Os,
{$ENDIF}
  FMX.DialogService;

{$R *.fmx}
{$R *.LgXhdpiPh.fmx ANDROID}

constructor TCameraRollForm.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  FRawBitmap := TBitmap.Create(0, 0);
{$IFDEF ANDROID}
  FPermissionReadExternalStorage := JStringToString(TJManifest_permission.JavaClass.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
  FPermissionWriteExternalStorage := JStringToString(TJManifest_permission.JavaClass.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
{$ENDIF}
end;

destructor TCameraRollForm.Destroy;
begin
  FreeAndNil(FRawBitmap);
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TCameraRollForm.btnPhotoLibraryClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PermissionsService.RequestPermissions(['android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES', 'android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO', 'android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE' , FPermissionReadExternalStorage, FPermissionWriteExternalStorage], LoadPicturePermissionRequestResult, DisplayRationale)
end;

// Optional rationale display routine to display permission requirement rationale to the user
procedure TCameraRollForm.DisplayRationale(Sender: TObject; const APermissions: TClassicStringDynArray; const APostRationaleProc: TProc);
var
  I: Integer;
  RationaleMsg: string;
begin
  for I := 0 to High(APermissions) do
  begin
    if APermissions[I] = FPermissionReadExternalStorage then
      RationaleMsg := RationaleMsg + 'The app needs to load photo files from your device';
  end;
  // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* - don't block this thread waiting for the user's response!
  // After the user sees the explanation, invoke the post-rationale routine to request the permissions
  TDialogService.ShowMessage('The app needs to read a photo file from your device to show it to you',
    procedure(const AResult: TModalResult)
    begin
      APostRationaleProc;
    end)
end;

procedure TCameraRollForm.LoadPicturePermissionRequestResult(Sender: TObject; const APermissions: TClassicStringDynArray; const AGrantResults: TClassicPermissionStatusDynArray);
begin
  if (Length(AGrantResults) = 5) and
     (AGrantResults[0] = TPermissionStatus.Granted) and
     (AGrantResults[1] = TPermissionStatus.Granted) and
     (AGrantResults[2] = TPermissionStatus.Granted) and
     (AGrantResults[3] = TPermissionStatus.Granted) and
     (AGrantResults[4] = TPermissionStatus.Granted) then
    TakePhotoFromLibraryAction1.Execute
  else
    TDialogService.ShowMessage('Cannot do photo editing because the required permissions are not granted');
end;

procedure TCameraRollForm.TakePhotoFromLibraryAction1DidFinishTaking(Image: TBitmap);
begin
  { Assign the image retrieved from the Photo Library to the TImage component. }
  imgPhotoLibraryImage.Bitmap.Assign(Image);
end;

end.
```

MANIFEST :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- BEGIN_INCLUDE(manifest) -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.embarcadero.CameraRoll"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0.0"
    android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23" android:targetSdkVersion="33" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_MEDIA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>
    <queries>

    </queries>
    <application
        android:persistent="False"
        android:restoreAnyVersion="False"
        android:label="CameraRoll"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:largeHeap="False"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:resizeableActivity="false"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.embarcadero.CameraRoll.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>




        <!-- Our activity is a subclass of the built-in NativeActivity framework class.
             This will take care of integrating with our NDK code. -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="CameraRoll"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <!-- Tell NativeActivity the name of our .so -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="CameraRoll" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="com.embarcadero.rtl.notifications.NotificationAlarm" />

    </application>
</manifest>
<!-- END_INCLUDE(manifest)
```

-->

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: And how do you know that permissions are not granted? Which ones?

Comment: I have edit my post with the code

Comment: Because the message "Cannot do photo editing because the required permissions are not granted" is display

Comment: I have in the manifest, it's edit

Comment: READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE should not be asked for on Android 33+ devices. It is always denied.

Comment: You better start telling why you think you need any of these permissions.

Comment: Remove READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE don't change the things

Comment: In my main app, I need to save a file on my device

Comment: Removing from manifest. But dont ask for it in code either.

Comment: On Android 33+ devices your app can create and write files in all private directories and in all public directories on external storage without needing any permission.

Comment: Removed in the code too

Comment: I believe you have just saved my life, thank you ! No permissions needed